# Is it possible to make HashSet subclass of Dictionary?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I'm trying to make a generic Type to handle all my references between  C# entities.

- In one case, a `reference` is simply an `int` ID, so the proper data structure to remember where ans entity it is been used, would be `HashSet<int>`
- In other scenario, An entity could be used in tree structure, so I need to remember both `int` Id and path which is a collection of objects. The proper data structure would a `Dictionary<int, Tvalue>`

Here is What I have so far:

```
public class References<TValue> : Dictionary<int, TValue>
{
}

public class References : HashSet<int>
{
}

public class MyEntityWithDefaultReferences
{
    public References References;
}

public class MyEntityWithPathReferences<PathType>
{
     public References<PathType> References;
}
```

Is there a way to make second `References` class inherit from the first one? So I can use parent class every where.

Comment: c# doesn't have multiple inheritance. you could use multiple interfaces.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt/21694054 This applies to `HashSet` and `Dictionary` as well.

Comment: Maybe you can use a [KeyedCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.keyedcollection-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: @Magnetron I can't see How can I use KeyedCollection if I need only the key

Comment: @Mhd let me see if I understood correctly, you have two classes, one is just an id, the other is id + a value and you want to store them both in the same Collection?

Comment: @Magnetron Actually, I need a collection that could store keys in one scenario. In another scenario,  keys and values.

Comment: Don't use inheritance for composition.

Answer (score 0):

Well, how about this way

```
public interface MyReference{
    int Id{get;set;}
}

public class SimpleReference : MyReference
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
}
public class CompoundReference<T> : MyReference
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public T TValue{get;set;}
}

public class ReferenceCollection : KeyedCollection<int, MyReference>
{
    protected override int GetKeyForItem(MyReference item)
    {
        return item.Id;
    }
}
```

And you can use like

```
SimpleReference sr = new SimpleReference(){Id=1};
CompoundReference<string> cr = new CompoundReference<string>(){Id=2,TValue="Test"};

ReferenceCollection col = new ReferenceCollection();
col.Add(sr);
col.Add(cr);
Console.WriteLine(col.Contains(1)); //true
Console.WriteLine(col.Contains(2)); //true
Console.WriteLine(col.Contains(3)); //false
var i1 = col[1]; //returns sr
var i2 = col[2]; //return cr
```